# ServiceProvider not found in ServiceLoader iteration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project that needs to use a ServiceLoader to be agnostic about impelemtations.

I want to run MainApp in Eclipse that has a Maven dependency to (external) Spi jar with in it the AProvider (interface declaring methodX) and the Service (iterating over serviceproviders). MainApp calls Service.methodX and should get an result from AProviderImpl that is in a external Sp.jar.

Sp.jar has a Maven dependency to Spi jar, and of course src/main/resources/META-INF/services/fullclassnameAProvider with in it fullclassnameAProviderImpl

So dependencies are like MainApp -> Spi <-Sp
And in Maven repo are Spi.jar, Sp.jar and MainApp.ear

The **problem** is that the iteration for(Sp sp : ServiceLoader.load(AProvider.class)) in Service does not find any serviceprovider.

I do NOT want to have Spi NOR MainApp know about Sp by dependency. Isn't that what the ServiceLoader is supposed to arrange?
Do I have to add explicitly Sp to the classpath of MainApp and if so how in Eclipse?

Or am I wrong assuming the Spi and Sp should be able to separate? I think not or am I?

Thank you for your consideration, Kenji

Comment: Does it work if you do the iteration in `MainApp`?

Comment: I placing a serviceprovider in the Spi.jar to see if that works, should be the same result as in MainApp, thanks.

Comment: Its not working and I do not understand it because Spi.jar is dependency of MainApp and has now also an implementation AProviderImpl and a resources/META-INF/services folder with fullclassnameAprovider file with in it fullclassnameAProviderImpl.
Yesterday this setup (spi and sp in same jar) did work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the SP the scope `runtime`, it'll only be used at runtime. One way or another: in the end SP must be on the classpath.

Comment: I did place Sp.jar as external jar in the MainApp classpath but no result, so now I am checking if placing the implementation in the Spi.jar makes any difference, thanks

Comment: Strangely enough renaming the jars and dependencies does make the jar with interface and implementation work.

Comment: Once I rename Sp.jar and rebuild it the loader stops working and reverting this and rebooting does not help, so it is not that the serviceloader only works at boot.

Comment: [Solved]
It was an inconsitency in the fullclassname of the SPI configuration file and I had to add the Sp.jar and Spi.jar to the shared library dircectory of my websphere server.